# begginers problem : why rotation/scaling/moving doesnt work on my mesh?

Tags: mirror

I'm just starting out and I follow this chair tutorial to train myself.
I use blender 2.90.1

The tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AP5CTAKckBI&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEL9UjPTLWQhLFAK7wVaRMR&index=3&t=1006s

at 18.35, we can see that it rotates the mesh without any problem.
I followed the tutorial to the letter, but I have a different result when I want to rotate my mesh :

1
[image: Text]

2 ('R' action)
[image: Text]

The part I mirrored doesn't move an inch. it's only the duplicated part that tilts as I want it to.

For info, if I apply the mirror modifier, it's not better.. The whole mesh doesn't want to lean at all !! :(
I also tried to move, resize, nothing works.
The chair leg seems blocked.

Whith ctrl A :
[image: Text]

Why that ? how to fix this problem? .
Thank you very much in advance !!

Answer (score 3):

Ohhhh yesss problem is finally resolved by myself.
here is the Error:
for some obscure reason, this box was checked :

[image]